# How to remove the box border?

Tags: html, css

I tried using overflow hidden, box-shadow none, background none, background color transparent, outline none, border 0, border-width 0px and border none, but it doesn't change. Is there any more option I can do? I'm currently not using JavaScript or jQuery. I'm not using any framework either. How to remove the border?

```css
header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  width: 98.5%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4em;
}

.navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
}


.navbar>ul>li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button1 {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.Header-Register {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
}

.Full-Name {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.gender {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.email {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.option {
  margin: 20px;
}

.Password {
  margin: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.Confirm-Password {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.Register {
  width: 5%;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: teal;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -190px;
  bottom: 120px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer-content{
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <header>
      <div class="banner-home">
        <div class="navbar">
          <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Products.html">Cosmetic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><button1>Login</button1></a>
        </div>
      <div class="Header-Register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
     <div class="content"> 
        <div class="Full-Name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="email">  
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="gender">
          <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
          <label for="radiobutton">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
          <label for="radiobutton">Female</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="option">
              <select>
                <option value="Jakarta">Jakarta</option>
                <option value="Bogor">Bogor</option>
                <option value="Depok">Depok</option>
                <option value="Tangerang">Tangerang</option>
                <option value="Bekasi">Bekasi</option>
              </select>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Password">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="Confirm-Password">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <div class="Register">
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;">Register</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
        <footer>
          <div>
              <ul class="socials">
                   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Clownehara" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012662688022" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/satrianavito/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              </ul>    
          <div class="footer-content">
              <p>Copyright Ⓒ 2022 [NAME]. All Rights Reserved.</p>
          </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: the border of which element?

Comment: the ones that cover full name, email, password and confirm password

Comment: How about removing `border-bottom` from `.email`, `.Password`, `.Confirm-Password`, etc? Although I'm not sure if I can understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to make it like this 

https://miro.medium.com/max/4800/1*v-qWjVkGMhtgHliFSoSJsw.png

Answer (score 0):

Juju. By default browsers may apply some defualt styling to input elements. You can opt-out this styling by setting `-webkit-appearance: none;`on the elements you wanna override.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want no border its:

```css
input {
  border: none;
}
```

If you want no border when the input has been clicked on its (in Chrome at least):

```css
input:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
input {
  border: none;
}

input:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  width: 98.5%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4em;
}

.navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
}

.navbar>ul>li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button1 {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.Header-Register {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
}

.Full-Name {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.gender {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.email {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.option {
  margin: 20px;
}

.Password {
  margin: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.Confirm-Password {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
}

.Register {
  width: 5%;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: teal;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -190px;
  bottom: 120px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer-content {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MediCare</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Register.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="banner-home">
      <div class="navbar">
        <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Products.html">Cosmetic</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
          <button1>Login</button1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="Header-Register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="Full-Name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="gender">
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Male">
        <label for="radiobutton">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="Female">
        <label for="radiobutton">Female</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="option">
          <select>
            <option value="Jakarta">Jakarta</option>
            <option value="Bogor">Bogor</option>
            <option value="Depok">Depok</option>
            <option value="Tangerang">Tangerang</option>
            <option value="Bekasi">Bekasi</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Password">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="Confirm-Password">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>
      <div class="Register">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;">Register</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div>
        <ul class="socials">
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Clownehara" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012662688022" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/satrianavito/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="footer-content">
          <p>Copyright Ⓒ 2022 [NAME]. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```